# Get the ASCII value of a character in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the ASCII value of a character is a string. I am essentially looking for the opposit of CHR, CHR(65)= A. Similarly fn(A) should return 65. I could not find any function in redshift SQL manual.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I could find is:

> ASCII is a deprecated leader node–only function.

You could write a [Python User-Defined Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) that returns a character given the ASCII value.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this is a basic function for every database to have in order to inspect special characters in the database.

Comment: I agree. Possibly getting out-of-date now that UTF-8 is common.