# Convert a varchar column to integer in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way in Amazon Redshift to convert a varchar column (with values such as A,B,D,M) to integer (1 for A, 2 for B, 3 for C...and so on) ? I know teradata has something like ASCII() but that doesn't work in Redshift.

Note: My goal is to convert the varchar columns to a number in my query and compare those two columns to see if the numbers are same or different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=be5f9e22d0cf6b8eea374a0bfcdf3b30)

---

**Postgres**:

```
SELECT 
    ascii(upper(t.letter)) - 64
FROM
    table t
```

Explanation:

- `upper()` makes the input to capital letters (to handle the different ascii value for capital and non-capital letters)
- `ascii()` converts the letters to [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). The capital letters begin at number 65.
- decrease the input by 64 to shift from ASCII starting point == 65 downto 1

---

**Redshift**:

The `ascii()` function is marked as deprecated on Redshift (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html)

So one possible (and more pragmatic) solution is to get a fixed alphabet string and give out the index for a given letter:

```
SELECT 
    letter, 
    strpos('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', upper(t.letter))
FROM 
    table t
```

Comment: I see that your sample code is working. But I get this error [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

Warnings:
Function "ascii(text)" not supported

Comment: Hm for Postgres it works. But it seems you are right, Redshift should not support this out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205362/get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-redshift

Comment: that's a great solution. Learned a new function.